# Include mobile specific content in core markup?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

In regards to mobile/desktop development - I like the idea of keeping with one website and update the viewing mode based on device size(ie. responsive design).

However, there are certain features I would like to introduce specifically to a mobile viewing mode. Namely, a navigation panel.

My question comes down to - should I add that content to the main body of the document, and hide it in the desktop version(css) and show it in the mobile viewing mode(css)?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how much more content you are adding for mobile.

Does the desktop version need this additional navigational panel, or would it be useful for desktop? If yes, then you may as well show it on desktop too (that's the easiest way around this). Keep in mind that search engines would be able to see the navigational panel, regardless of what CSS you use to hide the panel on desktop.

If it's just a trivial amount of content, you can use CSS to hide it. Just be careful to do it properly, or screen readers will still read it out to users on desktop. Bootstrap does it so to hide things to both sighted and blind users:

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide